# Reflecting square sequences?

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

For a regular cardinal $\kappa$, the principle $\square_{\kappa}$
asserts the existence of a sequence $C=\left\langle C_{\alpha}\mid\alpha\in\operatorname{Lim}(\kappa^{+})\right\rangle $
such that

1. $C_{\alpha}$ is club in $\alpha$;
2. If $\beta\in\operatorname{Lim}(C_{\alpha})$ then $C_{\beta}=C_{\alpha}\cap\beta$;
3. If $\operatorname{cf}({\alpha})<\kappa$ then $\left|C_{\alpha}\right|<\kappa$.

Let $K\subset\kappa$ be a non-empty set of regular cardinals. Say that $C$ *reflects* at $K$ if for every $\lambda\in K$, $C\cap\lambda^+=\left\langle C_{\alpha}\mid\alpha\in\operatorname{Lim}(\lambda^{+})\right\rangle $ is a $\square_\lambda$ sequence. This means we add the requirement:

4. For every $\lambda\in K$ and $\alpha<\lambda$, if $\operatorname{cf}({\alpha})<\lambda$ then $\left|C_{\alpha}\right|<\lambda$.

> **Edit:** to avoid triviality of simply "stacking" disjoint square sequences, we require also:
>
> 5. The set of $\alpha<\kappa^+$ such that $K^+\subset \operatorname{Lim}(C_{\alpha})$ is stationary where $K^+=\{\lambda^+\mid\lambda\in K\}$.

Has this notion been studied? A few questions I have:

1. Given specific $\kappa$, $K$ (such that $\square_\kappa$ holds), is there a $\square_\kappa$ sequence reflecting at $K$?
2. Given a specific $\square_\kappa$ sequence $C$, does it reflect at some $K$?  What is $\sup \{\lvert K\rvert \mid C \text{ reflects at }K\}$?
3. Given some $\kappa$ (such that $\square_\kappa$ holds), what is $\sup \{\lvert K\rvert \mid \text{there is a }\square_\kappa \text{ seq. reflecting at }K\}$?

> We might call the above suprema the *reflection number of $C$, $\square_\kappa$* respectively.

4. For some ordinal $\alpha$, is there any $\kappa$ with a $\square_\kappa$ sequence reflecting at some $K$ with order type $\alpha$?

Note that these questions may be asked in two contexts:

A. Under $V=L$ (or other canonical models).

B. What can consistently hold.